# How to call WebUserControls based on users request?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a website where i need to call WebUserControls (.ascx) based on the user request, how can I accomplish this? Is this even possible?

Example:

```
protected void userclick_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textbox1.Text == "2")
    {
        call WebUserControl1.ascx
    }
    else
    {
      /*do nothing*/
    }
}
```

I'm using C# for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does you mean? An ASCX is not a function.

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to give an example. I want to call WebUserControl named TotalSale.ascx if the id is equal to 2 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void userclick_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textbox1.Text == "2")
    {
        Control c1 = LoadControl("MyUserControl.ascx");
        //page or whatever control you want to add to
        Page.Controls.Add(c1);
    }
    else
    {
      /*do nothing*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call it and attach it to a `PlaceHolder`. Take a look-see at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx for details on the control.

It let's you fill in the PlaceHolder with anything you like at runtime. The advantage of this is that it allows you to put the PlaceHolder wherever you want it during design time and not just add it to the Page.Controls list.

```
protected void userclick_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textbox1.Text == "2")
    {
        WebUserControl1 uc = (WebUserControl1) Page.LoadControl("WebUserControl1.ascx"); 
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc); 
    }
    else
    {
      /*do nothing*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though you didn't accept it, this is the sole purpose of a PlaceHolder. I really suggest you utilize it over attaching to a random control.